# Python trouble exiting a 'while' loop for simple script

Tags: python, list, csv, matrix, reformat

I wrote a script to reformat a tab-delimited matrix (with header) into a "long format".  See example below.  It performs the task correctly but it seems to get stuck in an endless loop...

Example of input:

```
WHO   THING1    THING2
me    me1       me2
you   you1      you2
```

Desired output:

```
me    THING1    me1
me    THING2    me2
you   THING1    you1
you   THING2    you2
```

Here is the code:

```
import csv
matrix_file = open('path')
matrix_reader = csv.reader(matrix_file, delimiter="\t")


j = 1
while j:
    matrix_file.seek(0)
    rownum = 0
    for i in matrix_reader:
        rownum+=1
        if j == int(len(i)):
            j = False
        elif rownum ==1:
            header = i[j]
        else:
           print i[0], "\t",header, "\t",i[j]
    j +=1
```

I think it has to do with my exit command (j = False). Any ideas?

**edit:  Thanks for suggestions.  I think a typo in my initial posting led to some confusion, sorry about that**  For now I have employed a simple solution:

```
valid = True
while valid:
matrix_file.seek(0)
rownum = 0
for i in matrix_reader:
    rownum+=1
    if j == int(len(i)):
        valid = False

    etc, etc, etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`j+=1` is outside the while loop as senderle's answer says.

**other improvements can be:**

1. `int(len(i))` ,just use `len(i)` ,as `len()` always returns a int so no need of `int()` around
   it
2. use `for rownum,i in enumerate(matrix_reader):` so now there's no
   need of handling an extra variable `rownum`, it'll be incremented by
   itself.

**EDIT:** A working version of your code, I don't think there's a need of `while` here, the `for` loop is sufficient.

```
import csv
matrix_file = open('data1.csv')
matrix_reader = csv.reader(matrix_file, delimiter="\t")
header=matrix_reader.next()[0].split() #now header is ['WHO', 'THING1', 'THING2']

for i in matrix_reader:
        line=i[0].split()
        print line[0], "\t",header[1], "\t",line[1]
        print line[0], "\t",header[2], "\t",line[2]
```

Comment: Do you get the expected output with this fix?

Comment: I didn't think so, while you and @senderle are right about the `j+= 1` that's not the (only) problem ...

Comment: regarding point 1:  if I use that code I get an error since "i" isn't defined that point.  Point 2 works, and I didn't know about point 3, thanks

Comment: @alexhli point 1 is wrong :( , about point 3, `enumerate()` returns two values(index and item), so you were using `rownum` to see which row you're on(a kind of counter),so using `enumerate()` there's no need of defining another variable to counter the iterations.

Comment: @alexhli just to add, [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) can take a 2nd parameter to let you specify the starting value of the counter if ever needed - otherwise it's 0 by default.

Comment: +1 for the helpful notes on `enumerate` that I was too lazy to write, and for sticking to it -- I assumed the problem was solved too soon!

Answer (score 4):

Your `j += 1` is outside the `while` loop, so `j` never increases. If `len(i)` is never less than 2, then you'll have an infinite loop.

But as has been observed, there are other problems with this code. Here's a working version based on your idiom. I would do a lot of things differently, but perhaps you'll find it useful to see how your code *could* have worked:

```
j = 1
while j:
    matrix_file.seek(0)
    rownum = 0
    for i in matrix_reader:
        rownum += 1
        if j == len(i) or j == -1:
            j = -1
        elif rownum == 1:
            header = i[j]
        else:
           print i[0], "\t", header, "\t", i[j]
    j += 1
```

It doesn't print the rows in the order you wanted, but it gets the basics right.

Here's how I would do it instead. I see that this is similar to what Ashwini Chaudhary posted, but a bit more generalized:

```
import csv
matrix_file = open('path')
matrix_reader = csv.reader(matrix_file, delimiter="\t")

headers = next(matrix_reader, '')
for row in matrix_reader:
    for header, value in zip(headers[1:], row[1:]):
        print row[0], header, value
```

Comment: Do you get the expected output with this fix?

Comment: Sorry I had a mistake in my posted code, it has been corrected.  The "j+=1" was meant to be indented.  However, I think the error was due to mixing data types with "j" as both Boolean and int.

Comment: @alexhli, see my edit for a version of your code that works almost as expected. You might find it useful to think about why the changes I made were necessary.